# Nexmo Client Library for Node.js is working after getting deployed to AWS lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, vonage

*Created an issue on `nexmo/nexmo-node` repo, but posting here nevertheless for a greater reach*

I've deployed a phone number verifier lambda function through serverless. The `nexmo.message.sendSms` is working without an issue on my local dev environment (tested it with `serverless offline`). But I don't think it's working after deployed to AWS.

**Here's what I'm doing:**

```
const Nexmo = require('nexmo');
const privateKey = require('./privateKey');

const getNexmoInstance = (environment) => {
  const nexmo = new Nexmo({
    apiKey: environment.nexmoAPIKey,
    apiSecret: environment.nexmoAPISecret,
    applicationId: environment.nexmoAPPId,
    privateKey: Buffer.from(privateKey.key),
  }, {
    debug: true,
  });

  return nexmo;
};

const sendSMS = async (from, to, text, environment) => {
  const nexmo = getNexmoInstance(environment);
  nexmo.message.sendSms(from, to, text, { type: 'unicode' }, (err, responseData) => {
    console.log('nexmo err', err);
    console.log('nexmo responseData', responseData);
  });
  return null;
};
```

See that log messages inside the callback? (`console.log('nexmo err', err);`, etc). They're not showing up after deployed (As I said, working fine on local).

Since I set the `debug: true`, it's logging the following: 
- `info: sending message from +44750....` 
- `info: Request: { host: 'rest.nexmo.com', port: 443....`

But the callback is not getting called, no message log is registered on the Nexmo dashboard too. Is there any additional serverless related config that I'm unaware of?

- Nexmo package version: `2.6.0`
- Runtime: `nodejs12.x`

Comment: you are returning null before waiting for the callback to actually finish. you can promisify it or return the sendSms method and then return the result from there.

Answer (score 0):

Well from what I can see the issue is with the `return null` statement which returns before the callback is being fired and that's why you don't see any results.

also I don't see any reason to use `async` as well.

```
const sendSMS = (from, to, text, environment) => {
  const nexmo = getNexmoInstance(environment);
  return nexmo.message.sendSms(from, to, text, { type: 'unicode' }, (err, responseData) => {
    if(err) console.error(err);
    console.info(responseData);
    return;
  });
};
```

should do the trick.

if you could share your lambda handler/config it might be even easier to help you perfect this endpoint/function.